# Best methodology for evaluating a software architecture/ test software attributes like 'scalability' without specifics?

Tags: testing, architecture, software-design

I want to evaluate software without doing a detailled system test. For example: I don't want to test wether my software can handle a maximum of 20ms latency. I want to prove that my software's performance is scalable (by it's design). What kind of methodology would be appropiate?

Answer (score 0):

Scalability is all about theory of constraints.  Finding the choke-points of the system and understanding what it takes to relieve those choke-points.   It is very difficult to understand the performance scaling of a system without understanding all the functionality deeply enough to analyze those constraints.

Constraints generally have to do with state, and the movement of it from one part of the system to another.  The more atomic, and centrally managed this state is, the more likely it is to become a constraint.  For most systems this is a database of some sort, but for some it can be other resources such as a piece of state in-memory, or other resource.  If that has become decentralized, and the constraint is lifted, it becomes more of a constraint moving the state to the outer parts of the system (e.g. a browser or app).

This is not generally going to answer your question, but it should inform your approach to discovering the constraints and how to relieve them.  The idea that a design is "performant" inherently is very difficult to prove, there is always a constraint *somewhere* in the process, making sure that constraint is not too tight for your performance needs is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Scalability is the ability of the software to continue to perform in an acceptable manner when the system keeps getting bigger in terms of various factors. For example:

- Data: The growth of data size that system persists or processes.
- Traffic: The growth in volume of incoming/outgoing traffic increases
- Users:  The growth in the number of active users and thus simultaneous connections
- New Features / Operations: The increase in the number of features/operations supported by the system. Although this factor may fall into extensibility, it may affect scalability sometimes.

As per my understanding, you want to prove that the software is scalable but you do not care about proving the specific metrics that the system would be able to support. One approach could be to identify ALL the potential bottlenecks that would come into picture when the system gets bigger, document these bottlenecks and then document/demonstrate that the software would be able to overcome these bottlenecks. The metrics collection can be more work which is not required as you mentioned but performing a high level load test and giving a visual demonstration that the system is able to handle the load might be one of the ways. Not sure about the exact situation of yours but hope this helps.